# Ghostscript documentation

Tags: php, ghostscript

I want to know some information about ghostscipt and how is called from a web page using php to convert file formats..,please recommend some tutorials or books..as I want to further enrich my knowledge in this domain..

Comment: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/

Answer (score 1):

I think it unlikely you'll find this information in one place. Try learning the pieces separately:

- Running an external program from php.
- Using ghostscript to convert formats.